# Separable dual space implies existence of complete series

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, orthonormal

> Let $\{x_n\}$  be a basis for a Banach space $X$ and let $\{f_n\}$  be the associated 
>   sequence of coefficient functionals.  Prove or disprove: if $X^\ast$ is separable, then ${f_n}$ is complete (and hence a basis) in $X^\ast$.

I thought taking a space which is not Reflexive like $\ell^1(\mathbb{R})$  (sequences from $\mathbb{R}$).A dense countable subspace in ${\ell^1}^{\ast}(\mathbb{R})$  can be ${\ell^1}^\ast(\mathbb{Q})$ since rationals are countable dense subspace in the reals. I take the netural basis, where the $m$-th component of the $n$-th element is given by $e_n^m=\cases{1\quad m=n\\0\quad m\neq n}$. But then I cannot procceed proving that the $\{f_n\}$ are not complete. How can I do so?

Comment: Consider the summing basis of $c_0$, $(f_n)$ defined by  $f_n=\sum_{i=1}^n e_i$. The coefficient functionals are given by $f_n^*=e_{n}-e_{n+1}$. Their closed linear span does not contain $e_1$.

Comment: Why $f_n^\ast=e_n-e_{n+1}$?

Comment: You can verify directly that $f_n^* f_m=\delta_{n,m}$.

Comment: what does $\sigma_{n,m}$ stand for?

Comment: Sorry, $0$ if $n\ne m$, $1$ if $n=m$. (Should have been a "$\delta$"; it's edited now.)

Comment: thanks. Now, how verifying it helps us? is that a sufficient condition for a coeffient functionals?

Comment: Yes. It follows that $f_n^*$ agrees with the coefficient functional of $f_n$ on a dense subset of $c_0$ (the finite linear combinations of the $f_n$). So $f_n^*$ is indeed the coefficient functional of $f_n$.

Comment: why $$f_n^\ast f_m=\delta_{n,m}$$ means that $f_n^\ast$ agrees with the coefficient functional of $f_n$?

Comment: If $x=\sum_{i=1}^m\alpha_i f_i$, then by linearity $f_n^* x=\sum_{i=1}^m\alpha_i f_n^* f_i $. (Actually, by continuity of $f_n^*$, this holds for $x$ expressed as an infinite sum as well.)

Comment: Thanks. I think now I got it.